# CPU reaching 100% usage with select in python

Tags: python, select

I have a problem with a select in python, I have a piece of code which allow a client to receive data from a server and also send it by reading on stdin and writing on the server socket:

```
readfds = [s, sys.stdin]
writefds = [s, sys.stdout]
my_level = get_my_level(s)
is_co = True
cmd = ""
while (is_co):
    read, write, exception = select.select(readfds, writefds, [], 1)
    if (not (read or write or exception)):
        print "Timeout"
    else:
        for sock in read:
            if (sock == s):
                cmd = readline(s)
                print cmd
            elif (sock == sys.stdin):
                cmd = sys.stdin.readline()
                s.sendall(cmd)
     if (cmd == "mort"):
        is_co = False
```

I think it's because of the select is non-blocking but when I make it block it's the same thing. Can you explain wath is wrong in my code ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you mean in your title?

Comment: Can you explain more about what the problem is? 
Your CPU goes to 100%? If you never get "mort" you have an infinite loop, so your program keeps trying over and over... Except this appears to be by design. More info needed, please.

Comment: my CPU reaches 100% usage when I launch my code with this select

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably you can always write to `sys.stdout` so `select.select` should be returning immediately to let you know you can write to something. This code then processes the readable list, and then re-enters the loop. But nothing has changed with respect to `sys.stdout` so it continues to be writable.

This will execute in a tight loop and burn CPU.

Comment: @majined Make sure you "accept" this answer by clicking the checkmark next to it when you have a chance.  It will reward the answerer (+15) and you for being diligent and following-up (+2).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, so I continuously poll the socket (UDP in my case) and use sleep() timeout. In this code the CPU usage went from 100% to about 4%

```
sUDP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sUDP.bind((host, portIn))
sUDP.setblocking(0)
sUDP.settimeout(0.5)

while True:
    try:
        data, addr = sUDP.recvfrom(4096)
        ... #some data processing code here
    except:
        time.sleep(0.02)
```

Comment: If you aren't using UDP, adding a sleep like this at the bottom of your select poll will achieve the same for TCP