# Python select() consumes 100% CPU

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to create an application which creates a socket and prints incoming data as they appear at socket. [select is the preferred method to work with sockets](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/sockets.html#non-blocking-sockets) so I wrote this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from select import select
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 2345))
s.setblocking(False)  # True did not change anything
#s.settimeout(2)      # same behavior if uncommented

s.send(("give me data\n").encode("latin1"))

while True:
    readers, writers, err = select([s], [s], [])
    if s in readers:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print(data)
    # some kind of sleep here?
```

However this is code sample **consumes 100 % of one CPU core**.

What is the correct way to wait for data coming from a socket without this endless loop while having non-blocking socket? I need it to check if the connection is still alive. There is a similar question [CPU reaching 100% usage with select in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431690/cpu-reaching-100-usage-with-select-in-python) but it does not clearly explain why some kind of sleep is necessary.

Comment: Unsure if it's a duplicate, but answers on this page may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431690/cpu-reaching-100-usage-with-select-in-python

Comment: You really want to uses the [`selectors` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html#examples) here.

Comment: Most then likely your `select` returns immediatly because your socket is **always** ready to write.

Comment: You are adding `s` to the list of "write" selectors but not doing any writing. Thus, select always returns immediately with ready for writing. Don't select on an operation you're not actually doing

Comment: But yes, 'some kind of sleep' would otherwise be the answer here; `time.sleep(0.1)`. If you are not going to write in your loop, don't put your socket in the writers list (it is ready to write to almost all the time).

Comment: You should only include a socket in your write-selectors-list if you have some data you want to immediately send on that socket ASAP, and therefore need `select()` to return as soon as there is space in that socket's output-buffer to hold it.

Comment: Thanks for noticing about unused write selectors. After I removed socket from the wlist the 100% CPU usage dropped.

Answer (score 2):

The way you call it (`readers, writers, err = select([s], [s], [])`), it immediately returns if it is readable or writable. But you only check if it is readable.

As the socket is probably writable in most cases, this is exactly what you are told.

Another possibility could be to add a `time.sleep(0.02)` somewhere, e. g. when you don't do anything else in that loop. Then, 20 ms of extra delay shouldn't hurt (however, it is not clean).

Answer (score 2):

The most common use for a select is to only considere the `rlist` and `timeout` parameter. For your example code, it should then be:

```
while True:
    readers, writers, err = select([s], [], [])
    if s in readers:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print(data)
```

The `wlist` parameter is only used when the application may have to write large data. In that case, the data to be written to a socket is just queued and the socket is added to the `wlist`. When the `select` returns and there is something to write to a socket, the program tries to write and if something remains it is pushed again to the queue (beware: must be pushed to the head part...) and the socket is left in `wlist`. If everything was written and the queue is empty, then the socket is removed from `wlist`.

In the above text the *queue* could be a true double end queue, or a simple `bytes` buffer or any other container allowing bytes to be added on both ends. An one should exists per socket.